# Remove all Customer related pages

Tags: magento2, layout, customer, customer-account

I would like to remove all customer related pages. I have already removed all links like login / register, but the pages are still accessible via the url (so people with basic Magento 2 knowledge can access these pages).

Is there a way to remove these pages, together with their url's?

Comment: you can do these things by magento event observer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution: Implement an observer which monitors controller actions via predispatch and redirect them to no-route/404.